# Can I publish apps on Google Play with different package names?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, java-package

My question is **not** if I can upload two apps with the package names `<TLD>.<name>.app` and `<TLD>.<name>.app2`. (the app's name changes here)

It is if I can upload 2 apps with the package names `<TLD>.<name>.app` and `<anotherTLD>.<name>.app` on Google Play. (the top-level domain changes here, for example, one with "com" and another with "org")

Also, can 2 of my apps have different `<name>`s?

Will I have to have another Google Play Developer account for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can publish two applications with different package names. So you can publish `<TLD>.<name>.app` and `<anotherTLD>.<name>.app`. For Google play app they are treated as strings so they will be considered as different